# Trying to access files outside my user directory on the mac command line

Tags: macos

I'm trying to use the command tools for java instead of eclipse.
I'm new to the mac, it seems like the command line only allows you to see the files in your user directory? I tried to go ...  My java project files are stored on the system hard drive /javaprojects/....

Is there a way to use the command line outside the user directory? or does mac not allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can, you just need to specify the path to the files you want to work with.  Paths that start with "/" (called absolute paths) start from the root of the startup volume:

```
ls /javaprojects  # shows the contents of "javaprojects" at the root of the volume
cd /javaprojects  # moves to /javaprojects
touch examplefile  # creates /javaprojects/examplefile
```